# How to Supress / permently Hide error box of windows media player

Tags: visual-studio

HI i wanted to Hide this error box:

[image]

i tried serching on internet but did not find usefull results , i am a fresher in coding so any way or any code that can help me ?

This issue is caused from server not acsepting first time but secind time it works great .
it would be great if u provide me easy steps .

MY Currrent code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Media_Player
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label2.AutoSize = true;
            label1.AutoSize = true;
            

           
           

        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ("http://y0b.net/radiosa.m3u");
            MessageBox.Show("Successfuly Selected Radio SA , you will encounter a error , click close and then click play .  " , "Thank You" , MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            label2.Text = "Playing Radio SA";
        }

       

       

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ("http://y0b.net/radiosa2.m3u");
            MessageBox.Show("Successfuly Selected Radio SA Clasic , you will encounter a error after this mesage , click close and then click play .  ", "Thank You", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            label2.Text = "Playing Radio SA CLASSIC ";



        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();

                }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

        }

       

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Visible = false;
            
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            radioButton1.Checked = false;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ("http://y0b.net/radiosa3.m3u");
            MessageBox.Show("Successfuly Selected Radio SA Dance Department , you will encounter a error after this mesage , click close and then click play .  ", "Thank You", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            label2.Text = "Playing Radio SA Dance Department";
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = trackBar1.Value;
            label4.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
            
        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.playCount.ToString();
        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. I suppressed the error message by setting [enableErrorDialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/wmplibiwmpsettings-iwmpsettings-enableerrordialogs--vb-and-c) to false, then repeatedly asked it to play every 250 ms in a loop, with a ten second time out:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;

    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.autoStart = true;
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.enableErrorDialogs = false;
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "http://y0b.net/radiosa3.m3u";

    DateTime stopAt = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
    while (DateTime.Now<stopAt && axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState!=WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        await Task.Delay(250);
    }
    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState != WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to load stream!");
    }

    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Music started playing after about two seconds for me. Your mileage may vary...

Note that I added `async` to the method handler at the top to allow the use of `await Task.Delay(250);`.